# Semi-supervised learning on graphs

Tags: graph-theory, machine-learning

What is semi-supervised learning on graphs? We have been told that if we just have a function which has an input graph, or a given graph with labeled nodes, we should be able to predict labels on other nodes of the graph. This is not clear.

Comment: Why the down votes? The question may not be formulated properly, but there's substance in it?

Comment: yes it was not clear. were you told in a class by an instructor? it seems to be a general case of semi supervised learning, applied to labels on graphs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semi-supervised learning means that you get both labelled and unlabelled data as your input. The graph part means that there is also a relation defined for your datapoints. What exactly it is that you learn and how you use the graph structure depends on the problem. Here is a thorough exploration of the subject: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~zhuxj/pub/thesis.pdf